# ELI5: .es6.html, .json.html, .js.html, etc

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have only ever seen plain HTML files, but working on a project, I've noticed that there are several variations of *.html files. I am using BeautifulSoup to extract everything in the class parameter, but I'm not sure if BS4 is going to work on these types.

Are these filetypes just combinations of HTML & whatever other language appears before the period, as hinted by the filenames? Would these technically be HTML filetypes, or are they their own kind of filetype?

Could BeautifulSoup parse these special filetypes?

Comment: I don't think these are really standard file extensions. To help you figure out what these even are, I think you'd need to share the contents. But if your main question is: 'can my HTML parser read this', I would recommend just giving it a shot.

Comment: @Evert So I did just that, and BS4 can actually parse these various extensions. I think it's just a filenaming convention and to give more information about the contents - is not actually a standard file ext like you are saying. I will update this with my own Answer.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

It appears that these are not actually standard filename extensions - since BS4 can parse these variously-named *.html files just fine... I think these files are just named this way to provide more information to people reading the filenames.

Note: These are filenames from an open source project.